# how do i return a value to an outside function, from the inside function?

Tags: javascript

how do i return the average of `times` when the while statement inside the EventListener  finishes? i was thinking of adding a `set variable(){}` but, it is in a function which I just realized.
so... how do i return a value to an outside function, from the inside function?

```
function pingr(url){
      var times = [];
      var pinger = new WebSocket(url||"wss://speedtest.yimmee.repl.co");
      pinger.onmessage = (message)=>{
        times[JSON.parse(message).id] = Date.now() - startTime;
      };
      pinger.onerror = (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        times.length = 10;
      }
      pinger.addEventListener("open", ()=>{
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        pinger.send(JSON.stringify({
          id: Date.now()
        }));
        while(times.length < 10){}
        pinger.close();
      });
      /*
        if i run the while here, the ws will never connect, because the while prevents it from connecting.
        while needs websocket open in order to be finite
      */
      return Math.average(times);
      //Math.average is just a function that takes in an array to average it.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called scope.

```
let times = [];

function pingr(url) {
  // keep function the same except without the `var times = ` line
  var pinger = new WebSocket(url||"wss://speedtest.yimmee.repl.co");
  ...
}

pingr(whateverURL)
console.log(times)
```

Moving the variable to outside the function changes the scope of the variable, allowing access the "level above".

Comment: well, return statements *are* optional. I haven't tested it but thank you.

Comment: tested, but the debugger is broken. on one browser, the ```WebSocket``` will not fill the `pinger` var just because it is a `var`. on another browser the debugger just won't show me what happens after it sets `onerror`